# Truth in Fiction, Liabilities

Tags: character-development, legal

Are there guidelines for characters who are based on real people in a fiction novel? For example, I have a character who is patterned after an eccentric local elected official. Of course, different name, different family composition, but the pattern of his personal oddness is similar. Do I just throw in a couple of fictitious eccentric behaviors, differing from his normal and well known bizarre behavior? Can I use actual events that have happened? (Example: He is a frequent bar hopper, and seeks an audience of building video surveillance cameras when he needs to urinate. There was even a top 10 mix-video that circulated several years ago, satirized as a "Visit Our Lovely Little Town" ad.) Would I get sued?

Comment: Depends on jurisdiction. You can get away with a lot writing about American president in US, but not so much about, say, Thai king in Thailand.

Comment: Given that perspective, I am not so sure about a County Court Judge somewhere in Appalachia. Getting sued might be the LEAST of my problems.

Answer (score 1):

*(Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, and even if I were I still couldn't give legal advice here)*

I think it's unlikely you'd get sued, for a number of reasons:

- [People are not often sued for libel in fiction](http://www.rightsofwriters.com/2010/12/could-i-be-liable-for-libel-in-fiction.html)
- [Public figures are fair game to an extent](https://careerauthors.com/real-people-in-fiction/), especially if you make it satire.
- It's only libel if it's untrue and malicious.
- Suing you would bring more attention to his (mis)behaviour.
- Your work of fiction would need to get to his attention first.

I also suspect that if you did somehow get sued, and somehow lost, that the sales from all the extra attention would make up for any damages you'd have to pay. (Though whether that's worth the stress is another matter.)

Personally I'd be inclined to slap on the ["all persons fictitious" disclaimer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_persons_fictitious_disclaimer), and just pretend the character's *not* based on a real person.

Comment: Thank you. Good points and solid advice!

Comment: This is good advice for the US, but laws vary around the world, just so people are aware (Alexander mentions this in a comment). In particular laxer rules for public figures, the value of disclaimers, and a requirement for malice, may differ. Also, hoping sales from extra attention will cover costs might work if you're a big media outlet or famous writer, but is less likely to be true if you're a nobody and the media isn't even interested in you getting sued ("local character sues minor author" isn't going to make the national news).

Answer (score 0):

With respect to your specifics of a Judge in a county court in the United States (based on the location given in the comments) the Judge would count as a Public Figure under the U.S. legal definition which typically covers "Celebrities, elected officials, and those directly appointed by elected officials (All U.S. Judges are one of the latter two)."  There is also a transition from private to a limited public figure if you do any action where you might be on a 15 minutes of fame but defamation unrelated to your initial celebrity might still not qualify.  Additionally, most courts reject limited public person status if the reason you are famous is the subject of the defamation suit (i.e. someone writes a news article smearing you for something you did not do or deliberately misrepresented the initial facts.).

As a quick note, since it doesn't make much of a difference, but in the U.S. there are no county level judges.  All judges are state level, with state court houses set up in each county within a state that a judge may work at (Usually the courthouse is in the County Seat aka the capitol city of the County).  States that allow elected judges may have judges run for positions in the one county, but they are still state level officials.

As mentioned in other comments, there is also protection for those in U.S. Jurisdiction from "court shopping" for courts with more plaintiff friendly courts to defamation.  The U.S. by law will not enforce judgements of foreign courts in defamation matters UNLESS the case would produce the same finding of guilt in the United States, which is difficult because the U.S. is one of the few common law jurisdictions that retains Juries for civil cases, meaning that the most similar countries in laws to the U.S. would likely fail on the grounds that the conviction was found by a judge, not a jury (Not a lawyer either, so don't hold me to it.).

I highly recommend you bring this question to the Law stack exchange, which is a better suit to answer than writing.